# Apple Connect Review What does placeholder prices mean exactly?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

We have prepared our corporate shopping application for android and ios.
It was released in Play store without any problem, but we are having problems with Apple store.
They examined the application and returned with the following error.

Apple Connect Message From Review:

> Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content. Specifically, your app still contains placeholder prices.
>
> Before you submit your app to the App Store, all of its content and metadata must be final. Your app must not include placeholder or incomplete information. For example, an app with “lorem ipsum” text in the app description field will be rejected. Likewise, an app with placeholder screenshots, such as “screenshot coming soon,” will be rejected. Instead, you should only submit an app with complete information and content throughout.

These are the screenshots sent by Apple:

[image]

[image]

The places marked in the red boxes indicate the prices of the products.
I am testing the .ipa file on my real iPhone. Pictures that are not uploaded are also uploaded.
I don't understand, what's really the problem, should we not write the price?

Comment: “Pictures that are not uploaded are also uploaded.” What does that mean?

Comment: @Macmade While reviewing on the second image in post , picture of product is not showing :) But the main problem is placeholder prices what does it mean exactly? There ara different kind of jewellery apps that showing prices unsur the product

Comment: They probably think your prices are placeholder texts - that is texts used in development instead of real prices. The reviewer probably doesn’t know about the Turkish Lira. Simply reply and contest the rejection

Comment: Or they may actually be right - does this jewelry really cost 2 million US dollars?

Comment: @Macmade The price value is false because of review is on emulator. While converting string value to double value if I use comma real device true but emulator false , if I use dot real device false but emulator true.. strange thing but it may be causes the problem like this

Comment: Then you know what you need to fix then...

Comment: @Macmade I will fix it and try to upload a new build :) I hope problem solves.. Thanks for your interest:)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app store review is off topic

Answer (score 1):

> Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content. Specifically, your app still contains placeholder prices.

It means that your running app can't contain placeholder text. Or can't contain test data or image inside app.

From shared screenshot, we can not see the real information from the application. Maybe your app is using a test web api in a develop environment, but make sure that using a real web api before submitting to the Apple Store.

In addittion, it's common for storyboards to contain various types of placeholders. That's ok as long as they are replaced when running the app.